# How to solve Autoload error using hyva theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, hyva

I am learning hyva theme for magento 2. Learning about hyva-react-checkout and Whenever I try to run any magento cli command, I get this error,

```
Autoload error: Module 'Hyva_ReactCheckout' from '/var/www/hyva/public/vendor/hyva-themes/magento2-react-checkout/src' has been already defined in '/var/www/hyva/public/vendor/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-checkout/src'
```

How Do I solve this? I only installed couple of packages relating to hyva checkout and hyva-react-checkout. The commands I ran are following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hyva-themes/magento2-react-checkout** vs **hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-checkout** conflicts, you have to remove one of them.

**hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-checkout** is the old name of the hyva checkout module and **hyva-themes/magento2-react-checkout** is the new name of the hyva checkout module

So, you should remove `hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-checkout` from your composer.json and remove `vendor/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-checkout` folder.

Then run `composer install` and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and re-compile DI by run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and re-deploy static content if requires.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that!